# How to install IIS7 on Windows 7, 32bit using WIX3.5 MSI setup

Tags: xml, windows, installation, wix, windows-installer

I am new to WIX and i am trying write a wix msi for install the IIS7 on windows 7 32bit pc.

is any one tried this, if yes please help on this, sample code also will help me lot , thanks

Comment: Um, setup development *IS* development.  This isn't off topic at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Quiet Exeuction Custom Action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm) in WiX to call [DISM /LOCAL to install](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/08/14/how-to-install-iis-7-5-on-windows-7-using-the-command-line.aspx) the Windows Features needed for IIS and/or ASP.NET.

Comment: hi thanks for ur reply, do have any sample wix app which will install IIS7, i am new to wix,

Comment: @user1120572 try it yourself and ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't feel like doing the homework of someone with a reputation of 6 who probably won't accept the answer anyways.